# Multiple filter for one datatable in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am working on Angular 2. In one of my scenario I have to add multiple filters for one DataTable. I have created custom DataTable for my project.

Filters like: 
[image]

After searching on google and review answer on stackoverflow I found this Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/e0PCIsqXumbXe6mAUWBI?p=preview

I have code as in plunker but not working for me.

My Code:

Pipe:

```
transform(items: Array<any>, filter: {[key: string]: any }): Array<any> {
    return items.filter(item => {
            let notMatchingField = Object.keys(filter)
                                         .find(key => item[key] !== filter[key]);

            return !notMatchingField; // true if matches all fields
        });
}
```

Component Html:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of dataresult | jbgridfilter: filterItems | orderBy : [orderbyKey, 'ID']  | paginate: { itemsPerPage: numOfPages, currentPage: p }"
                      (click)="showRowDetails(item)">
                      <td *ngFor="let key of keysArray;"><span>{{item[key]}}</span></td>
                      <tr>
```

Component Class:

```
valueForFilter(key, event) {
      let item = {key: event};
      this.filterItems.push(item);
    }
```

Note that: the table is dynamic, means the fields can be any not fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated the plunker here https://plnkr.co/edit/sJD1uQpkyBojzzt8nUps?p=preview

In valueForFilter, filterItems is an object not an array (at least in the plunker example), so push won't work for you.

```ts
updateFilter(key,value){
  this.peopleFilter[key] = value; 
}
```

In addition, you need to set the piple as impure

```ts
@Pipe({
    name: 'filter'
    pure: false 
})
```

I hope this helps

Comment: I have set `pure: false` but the error is still there

Comment: did you look at the link I posted? did you also fix the code to update your object?

Comment: Yes @bakerhumadi I have do the changes as you have say, also set pipe to impure. But the same error "Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined" in console.

Comment: Can you update the original plunker with your code changes so I can look at what's wrong directly?